# Calling Javascript method defined above on page load

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am brand new to JavaScript so bear with me.  I have a JavaScript function that is on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.debug = true;
    var popup;
    Sys.require(Sys.components.popup, function () {
        popup = Sys.create.popup("#popup", {
            parentElementID: "target",
        });
    });
</script>
```

It works perfectly when I use it as an event:

```
<input type="button" onclick="popup.show()" value="Edit Theme" style="float: right; margin-right: 7.25em;" />
```

I want to call it on page load, inside the body tag I have the following code:

```
<script>
    window.onload = popup.show;
</script>
```

The method does not appear to get called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try : `window.onload = popup.show;`

Comment: I would open up your browsers developer kit to view your JavaScript step by step as it runs on your page.  Check the console for error messages, it may lead you directly to the problem.

Comment: Error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Comment: what is the order of the script tags on the page?

Comment: Is this `Sys.require` ASP.Net script loader? If it is you need to show the pop up when the script has loaded.

Comment: I am using asp.net server controls. The window.onload = popup.show; is at the end of the page after all asp.net server controls....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the  [documentation](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Load%20Required%20Scripts.ashx)  on Sys.Require, it seems that Sys.Require is called on load, which means that based on the [ASP.Net page lifetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx) the script hasn't loaded when the onload event fires.

It looks like you can use [Sys.onReady()](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Detect%20DOM%20Ready.ashx) instead:

```
Sys.onReady(function(){
    popup.show();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write:

```
window.onload = popup.show;
```

Comment: @DavidTunnell is `Sys.require` asynchronous?

Comment: I don't know. I used a tutorial to make the inline popup.. I'm looking for it now...